# Create form by Ext.FormPanel

Tags: extjs

```
form= new Ext.FormPanel({ 
    renderTo: Ext.query(".foo")[0], 
    items:[]

});
```

In firebug HTML-code :

```
<div class="foo" id="ext-gen1008">
<div id="form-1014" class="x-panel x-panel-default" role="form" style="width: 1024px; height: 2px;">
<div id="form-1014-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-panel-body-default" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<div class="x-clear" role="presentation" id="ext-gen1011"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Where is the form tag? Or is there no form tag and is this form submit by Ajax?

Comment: What extjs version are you using (2.x, 3.x, 4.x)? And what is your goal?

Comment: I use version Extjs 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't care about html. ExtJS is a javascript framework that takes care of those things for you. (You shouldn't write tag dependent code? In future releases sencha could modify it and you will have to rewrite/update your code if you do.)

If you provide the form with an url parameter, you can just call `.submit()` on your form to submit the values.

Here you find an example in [the documentation](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel)

The documentation's example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Form',
    bodyPadding: 5,
    width: 350,

    // The form will submit an AJAX request to this URL when submitted
    url: 'save-form.php',

    // Fields will be arranged vertically, stretched to full width
    layout: 'anchor',
    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%'
    },

    // The fields
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        name: 'first',
        allowBlank: false
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
        name: 'last',
        allowBlank: false
    }],

    // Reset and Submit buttons
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Reset',
        handler: function() {
            this.up('form').getForm().reset();
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Submit',
        formBind: true, //only enabled once the form is valid
        disabled: true,
        handler: function() {
            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
            if (form.isValid()) {
                form.submit({
                    success: function(form, action) {
                       Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
                    },
                    failure: function(form, action) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result.msg);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Unrelated but helpful, before Ext 4.x we used the `new` keyword to create new components, now it's advised to use `Ext.create`. And instead of `Ext.extend`, we use `Ext.define` now and add an extend parameter.

[Upgrade Guide](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/upgrade)

Comment: @VDP A minor correction: Ext.create has its useful side but using it blindly instead of `new` is not recommended because it adds noticeable overhead to object creation. It comes handy when you don't want to hardcode class names, but in most cases plain old `new` is more than sufficient.

Comment: @AlexTokarev I haven't thought about that. Good point! It has it's overhead. I've misinterpreted the documentation a little there. But weighing the overhead vs maintainability, most of the time I still prefer `Ext.create` / `Ext.widget`